# How to take a screenshot of Android's Surface View?

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview

I want to programatically take screen shot of my game, just as you'd get in Eclipse DDMS.

Screenshot taken through the solution proposed here: [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) and in most other SO questions only have View elements visible, but not the SurfaceView.

```
SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshots/";
// Get root view
View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
// Create the bitmap to use to draw the screenshot
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// Get current theme to know which background to use
final Theme theme = activity.getTheme();
final TypedArray ta = theme
    .obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.windowBackground });
final int res = ta.getResourceId(0, 0);
final Drawable background = activity.getResources().getDrawable(res);

// Draw background
background.draw(canvas);

// Draw views
view.draw(canvas);

// Save the screenshot to the file system
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    final File sddir = new File(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS);
    if (!sddir.exists()) {
        sddir.mkdirs();
    }
    fos = new FileOutputStream(SCREENSHOTS_LOCATIONS
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    if (fos != null) {
        if (!bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos)) {
            Log.d("ScreenShot", "Compress/Write failed");
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: so you want to capture the view that are not visible or are beneath some other view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Take Screenshot of Surface View Shows Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this also useful for you. here little difference for the above answer is 
      for I used glsurfaceview to take the screen shots hen i click the button.
      this image is stored in sdcard for mentioned folder :
      sdcard/emulated/0/printerscreenshots/image/...images

```
 My Program :

 View view_storelayout ;
 view_storelayout = findViewById(R.id.gl_surface_view);

   button onclick() {

   view_storelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 

view_storelayout.buildDrawingCache(true);

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view_storelayout.getDrawingCache());
view_storelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos); 
                byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);

                final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
                 long mytimestamp=c.getTimeInMillis();
                String timeStamp=String.valueOf(mytimestamp);
                String myfile="hari"+timeStamp+".jpeg";

 dir_image=new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
      File.separator+"printerscreenshots"+File.separator+"image");
                dir_image.mkdirs();

                try {
                    File tmpFile = new File(dir_image,myfile); 
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        int len;
                        while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                        }
                            fis.close();
                            fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "myPath:"
            +dir_image.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("hari", "screenshots:"+dir_image.toString());

  }

 Note :
          But, here i am faced one problem. In this surfaceview , i drawn line and circle
  at runtime. after drawn some objects, when i take screenshots , its stored only for
  black image like surfaceview is stored as an image.

 And also i want to store that surfaceview image as an .dxf format(autocad format).
 i tried to stored image file as an .dxf file format.its saved successfully in 
 autocad format. but, it cant open in autocad software to edit my .dxf file.
```

Answer (score 1):

The code from the Usman Kurd answer will not work is most cases.

Unless you're rendering H.264 video frames in software with Canvas onto a View, the drawing-cache approach won't work (see e.g. this answer).

You cannot read pixels from the Surface part of the SurfaceView. The basic problem is that a Surface is a queue of buffers with a producer-consumer interface, and your app is on the producer side. The consumer, usually the system compositor (SurfaceFlinger), is able to capture a screen shot because it's on the other end of the pipe.

[Take Screenshot of SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086263/take-screenshot-of-surfaceview/25086739#25086739)