# Take Screenshot of SurfaceView

Tags: android, camera, screenshot, surfaceview

Am developing a simple camera app. I have code that takes screenshot of the whole activity and writes it to the SD card. The problem is that the `SurfaceView` returns a black screen.

I would like to know how to independently take a screenshot of the `SurfaceView` only. Here is the code that takes the screenshot of the whole activity.

```
findViewById(R.id.screen).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        layout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        saveBitmap(bitmap);
    }
});

public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}


public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final MediaPlayer cheer = MediaPlayer.create(PicShot.this, R.raw.shutter);
    cheer.start();
    
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";

    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fname);
    FileOutputStream fos;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        layout.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/*");
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

The SurfaceView's surface is independent of the surface on which View elements are drawn.  So capturing the View contents won't include the SurfaceView.

You need to capture the SurfaceView contents separately and perform your own composition step.  The easiest way to do the capture is probably to just re-render the contents, but use an off-screen bitmap as the target rather than the surface.  If you're rendering with GLES to an off-screen pbuffer, you can use `glReadPixels()` before you swap buffers.

**Update:** [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "texture from camera" activity demonstrates handling live video from the camera with OpenGL ES.  `EglSurfaceBase#saveFrame()` shows how to capture GLES rendering to a Bitmap.

**Update:** See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/), which provides a bit more background.

Comment: Am an android newbie. please kindly post sample code on how to do that.thanks

Comment: Assuming all of your rendering is done to a Canvas you get from the Surface, just create a Canvas backed by a Bitmap (see e.g. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).  Depending on how the surfaces are composed, you can either blit one onto the other, or composite the pair onto a third.

Comment: Hi, the article you linked does not seem to cover the case of saving to bitmap a surfaceview showing a frame _from a Camera_ . Do you have some sample code for us?

Comment: The pixel data source doesn't matter -- once it's on the surface, it's just pixels.

Comment: Added a link to Grafika.

Comment: ... code samples or "what is needed to do" would be interesting as well. +1 for the hint to grafika

Comment: how would you use glReadPixels with surface view. It is kinda confusing, can you provide code sample?

Comment: Hi @chiayongkang did you get any solution for this case. If you have please post here

Comment: check this https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34

Answer (score 14):

**Just copy and past code**

> Note: only For API level >= 24

```
private void takePhoto() {

        // Create a bitmap the size of the scene view.
        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);



        // Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image.
        final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("PixelCopier");
        handlerThread.start();
        // Make the request to copy.
        PixelCopy.request(holder.videoView, bitmap, (copyResult) -> {
            if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                Log.e(TAG,bitmap.toString());
                String name = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                imageFile = ScreenshotUtils.store(bitmap,name);

            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getViewActivity(),
                        "Failed to copyPixels: " + copyResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            handlerThread.quitSafely();
        }, new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()));
    }
```

Comment: Yup This function will work for 24 and greater version Please see this:-->https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy

Comment: Any ideas below API 24? Because none of the answers worked for me.

Comment: yes you can use MediaProjection class to capture the entire screen with a virtual display, but it can not provide any pacific area for capturing . only work for entire screen

Comment: if you want to capture for a specified view you should have to use  PixelCopy class

Comment: why is the holder in holder.videoView an unresolved symbol?

Comment: @chiayongkang You have just need to pass your view instead of my `holder.videoView`

Comment: @ND1010_ is there the code for the Screenshot.utils class for the store function? Curious to see how you store the bitmap as well.

Comment: sometimes the object results in the image to have white parts. can it be solved with glReadPixels? if not how can i solve that?

Answer (score 4):

My situation related with `ExoPlayer`, need get `bitmap` of current frame

Works on *API >= 24*:

```
private val copyFrameHandler = Handler()

fun getFrameBitmap(callback: FrameBitmapCallback) {
    when(val view = videoSurfaceView) {
        is TextureView -> callback.onResult(view.bitmap)
        is SurfaceView -> {
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    videoSurfaceView.getWidth(),
                    videoSurfaceView.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            
            copyFrameHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
            
            PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, { copyResult: Int ->
                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    callback.onResult(bitmap)
                } else {
                    callback.onResult(null)
                }
            }, copyFrameHandler)
        }
        else -> callback.onResult(null)
    }
}

fun onDestroy() {
    copyFrameHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
}

interface FrameBitmapCallback {
    fun onResult(bitmap: Bitmap?)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your situation allows it, using a `TextureView` instead of a `SurfaceView` will make this problem a lot easier to solve. It has a method [`getBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#getBitmap()) that returns a `Bitmap` of the current frame on the `TextureView`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. Put this method in some `Util` class:

```
/**
 * Pixel copy to copy SurfaceView/VideoView into BitMap
 */
fun usePixelCopy(videoView: SurfaceView,  callback: (Bitmap?) -> Unit) {
    val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        videoView.width,
        videoView.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    );
    try {
        // Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image.
        val handlerThread = HandlerThread("PixelCopier");
        handlerThread.start();
        PixelCopy.request(
            videoView, bitmap,
            PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener { copyResult ->
                if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
                    callback(bitmap)
                }
                handlerThread.quitSafely();
            },
            Handler(handlerThread.looper)
        )
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        callback(null)
        // PixelCopy may throw IllegalArgumentException, make sure to handle it
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
usePixelCopy(videoView) { bitmap: Bitmap? ->
    processBitMp(bitmap)
}
```

**Note:** `VideoView` is a subclass of `SurfaceView`, so this method can take screenshot of video `View` as well.

Comment: Any reason why Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); surfaceView.draw(canvas); won't work?

Answer (score 1):

For those of us looking for a solution for API <= 24, this is what I did as a workaround. When user clicks button for capture, close the preview captureSession and create a new captureSession for still image capture.

```java
mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
mCaptureSession.close();
mCaptureSession = null;

mPreviewReader = ImageReader.newInstance(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, MAX_IMAGES);
mPreviewReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
    Arrays.asList(mPreviewReader.getSurface()),
    //Arrays.asList(mSurface),
    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
            try {
                final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                captureBuilder.addTarget(mPreviewReader.getSurface());
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
                captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(mOrientation));
                Log.d(TAG, "Capture request created.");
                mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            } catch (CameraAccessException cae) {
                Log.d(TAG, cae.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {}
    },
    mBackgroundHandler
);
```

Then at `onImageAvailableListener`, you can get the image with `imageReader.acquireNextImage()` to get the still captured image.