# Take a photo with surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview

I've tried to create an app that allows me to see in a SurfaceView what I see with the front Camera. I tried to implement a Button to allows me to take a screenshot of the Activity, because over the camera I have a mask. When I perform the screenshot I can capture only the screenshot of my mask that is over the surfaceView.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Is there anyone can help me?
My Intent is to create an app that allows me take a picture of my self whit a mask over my face.
Her is the example of my virtual device.
[image]
I've alredy tried with a real phone but nothing changed.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Handler.Callback {

    static final String TAG = "CamTest";
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1242;
    private static final int MSG_CAMERA_OPENED = 1;
    private static final int MSG_SURFACE_READY = 2;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(this);
    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    CameraManager mCameraManager;
    String[] mCameraIDsList;
    CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraStateCB;
    CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
    boolean mSurfaceCreated = true;
    boolean mIsCameraConfigured = false;
    private Surface mCameraSurface = null;
    Button btt_scatta;
    Bitmap immagine_screen;
    ImageView img_view_screen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Richiedo il Fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get root view from Activity
        final View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        btt_scatta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btt_scatta);
        img_view_screen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view_screen);
        img_view_screen.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        this.mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mCameraManager = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            mCameraIDsList = this.mCameraManager.getCameraIdList();
            for (String id : mCameraIDsList) {
                Log.v(TAG, "CameraID: " + id);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mCameraStateCB = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mCameraDevice = camera;
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_CAMERA_OPENED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDisconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        btt_scatta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                btt_scatta.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                immagine_screen = getScreenShot(rootView);
                store(immagine_screen,"screenshot Honor");
                img_view_screen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_view_screen.setImageBitmap(immagine_screen);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //requesting permission
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "request permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PERMISSION_ALREADY_GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraIDsList[1], mCameraStateCB, new Handler());
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            if (mCaptureSession != null) {
                mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }

            mIsCameraConfigured = false;
        } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
            // Doesn't matter, cloising device anyway
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IllegalStateException e2) {
            // Doesn't matter, cloising device anyway
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (mCameraDevice != null) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_CAMERA_OPENED:
            case MSG_SURFACE_READY:
                // if both surface is created and camera device is opened
                // - ready to set up preview and other things
                if (mSurfaceCreated && (mCameraDevice != null)
                        && !mIsCameraConfigured) {
                    configureCamera();
                }
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void configureCamera() {
        // prepare list of surfaces to be used in capture requests
        List<Surface> sfl = new ArrayList<Surface>();

        sfl.add(mCameraSurface); // surface for viewfinder preview

        // configure camera with all the surfaces to be ever used
        try {
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(sfl,
                    new CaptureSessionListener(), null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mIsCameraConfigured = true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    try {
                        mCameraManager.openCamera(mCameraIDsList[1], mCameraStateCB, new Handler());
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCameraSurface = holder.getSurface();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        mCameraSurface = holder.getSurface();
        mSurfaceCreated = true;
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SURFACE_READY);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSurfaceCreated = false;
    }

    private class CaptureSessionListener extends
            CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(final CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSessionConfigure failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigured(final CameraCaptureSession session) {
            Log.d(TAG, "CaptureSessionConfigure onConfigured");
            mCaptureSession = session;

            try {
                CaptureRequest.Builder previewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice
                        .createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mCameraSurface);
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(),
                        null, null);
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "setting up preview failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Capture the root view
    public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
        View screenView = view.getRootView();
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }

    //Store the Bitmap into the phone
    public static void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
        final String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Screenshots";
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I think that a good solution is to take a picture with the camera and then put in a Image view under my mask, and then take a screenshot. But the problem is to take a photo with the surfaceView: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086263/take-screenshot-of-surfaceview