# How can I take Screenshots using Arcore?

Tags: java, android, screenshot, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to take a screenshot of my Augmented Reality Screen and pass it as a bitmap to another activity.

This is the code that I am using to take the screenshot:

Function to take screen shot

```
public static void tmpScreenshot(Bitmap bmp, Context context){
        try {
            //Write file
            String filename = "bitmap.png";
            FileOutputStream stream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

            //Cleanup
            stream.close();
            bmp.recycle();

            //Pop intent
            Intent in1 = new Intent(context, CostActivity.class);
            in1.putExtra("image", filename);
            context.startActivity(in1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Function to receive screenshot

```
private void loadTmpBitmap() {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
        try {
            FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.test);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 120, 120, false));
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Even though the Screenshot was taken, it was black when it is passed to another activity.
In addition, the Screenshot only appeared after I pressed the back button

Can anyone help me with the code to take a screenshot with ARCore? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: On further research, i have found that i have to take a photo on the surface view.  Some of the existing questions that relates to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086263/take-screenshot-of-surfaceview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817577/android-take-screenshot-of-surface-view-shows-black-screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to take a screenshot of a SurfaceView using your method. If you do then the screenshot will be black, as it only works for regular views.

What you need to use is [pixelcopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy).

```
    private void takePhoto() {
    ArSceneView view = arFragment.getArSceneView();

    // Create a bitmap the size of the scene view.
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image.
    final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("PixelCopier");
    handlerThread.start();
    // Make the request to copy.
    PixelCopy.request(view, bitmap, (copyResult) -> {
        if (copyResult == PixelCopy.SUCCESS) {
            try {
                saveBitmapToDisk(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(VisualizerActivity.this, e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                return;
            }
            SnackbarUtility.showSnackbarTypeLong(settingsButton, "Screenshot saved in /Pictures/Screenshots");




        } else {

            SnackbarUtility.showSnackbarTypeLong(settingsButton, "Failed to take screenshot");

        }
        handlerThread.quitSafely();
    }, new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()));
}


public void saveBitmapToDisk(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {

  //  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +  "/Pictures/Screenshots/";

    if (videoDirectory == null) {
        videoDirectory =
                new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                + "/Screenshots");
    }

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

    File mediaFile = new File(videoDirectory, "FieldVisualizer"+formattedDate+".jpeg");

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mediaFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.flush();
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: When I use PixelCopy I have a screenshot without scene, because the scene looks transparent on the screenshot