# Take a Screenshot of an AR Screen In Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building a Jetpack Compose app that allows users to take a screenshot of an AR screen and save it to photo library by pressing a camera button.

However, when I press the camera button, the screenshot saved to my photo library is just an entirely black screen with a camera button showing.

I want it to take a screenshot of the AR screen (what camera seeing and objects added by AR) without the camera button. How do I do it?

This is my main function:

```
@Composable
fun Activity_3() {
    var captureScreenshot by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    if (captureScreenshot) {
        captureAndSaveScreenshot(LocalContext.current)
        captureScreenshot = false
    }
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            ARScreen()
            CameraButton {
                captureScreenshot = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my captureAndSaveScreenshot function:

```
@Composable
fun captureAndSaveScreenshot(context: Context) {
    val view = LocalView.current
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val resolver = context.contentResolver
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "AR_Screenshot_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        }
        val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
        uri?.let { imageUri ->
            resolver.openOutputStream(imageUri)?.use { outputStream ->
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Screenshot saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } ?: run {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to save screenshot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        val file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val filename = "AR_Screenshot_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
        val fileUri = file.absolutePath + "/" + filename
        try {
            file.createNewFile()
            val outputStream = file.outputStream()
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
            outputStream.close()
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(fileUri), null, null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Screenshot saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to save screenshot", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

===[Update]===

I adjusted my code by adding a call back `onViewReady: (View) -> Unit` and `onViewUpdated` to the `ARScreen` function, so the function looks something like this.

```
@Composable
fun ARScreen(onViewReady: (View) -> Unit) {
    ...
        onViewUpdated = {
            onViewReady(this)
        }
    ...
}
```

This is what I adjusted in the `Activity_3` function

```
@Composable
fun Activity_3() {
    var captureScreenshot by remember { mutableStateOf(value = false) }
    var arView by remember { mutableStateOf<View?>(value = null) }
    if (captureScreenshot) {
        arView?.let {
            captureAndSaveScreenshot(context = LocalContext.current, view = it)
        }
        captureScreenshot = false
    }
    ...
}
```

This is what I adjusted in the `captureAndSaveScreenshot` function

```
@Composable
fun captureAndSaveScreenshot(context: Context, view: View) {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)
    ...
}
```

Currently, the screenshot has no camera button anymore but it is still a black screen. What should I do?

Comment: Start with [How can I take Screenshots using Arcore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58665513/295004) but do read the links in the comment: [Take Screenshot of SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25086263/295004) and [Android Take Screenshot of Surface View Shows Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27817577/295004)

Comment: I'm a beginner in Kotlin and don't know much about Java. It would be nice if you have more related source written in Kotlin but thank you. I'll find the way.